# Derivative of $(\arcsin (x))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I was trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that $(\arcsin (x))'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$.

So far I got that $(\arcsin (x))'=\frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin (x))}$, but i don't know how to go from $\frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin (x))}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$. Set $\theta = \arcsin(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $g(x)= \arcsin(x) \in [ \frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} ]$
$\sin( g(x))=x \longrightarrow g'(x) \cos( g(x))= 1$ 
On the other hand, as $ g(x) \in [ \frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} ]$, we have:
$\cos( g(x))= \sqrt{1- \sin^2(g(x))}=\sqrt{1-x^2} $.
 So we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with a right angle at $B$. Let $AB=x\le1,AC=1$, then $\angle C=\arcsin x=\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

So we have $\arcsin(x)=\begin{cases}\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2},&0\le x\le1\\-\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2},&-1\le x<0\end{cases}$

where for $x\in[-1,0)$, we added a minus sign before $\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}$ since $\arcsin(-x)=-\arcsin(x)$.